# Liberty change web.xml apps/expanded to test

Tags: websphere-liberty

I just want to test a web app placed in `dropins` directory. It is expanded in `/apps/expanded` directory.

Can I change the web.xml file in this directory to test and revert. 
Do I need to restart the server. 
Will it affect war file in `dropins` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. See [this open issue](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/7182) for an explanation:

> Updates to application files which were made when the server was running are copied over on the next server restart.

Basically I believe, for now, you will to edit the `web.xml` in you web app archive and then restart the server; otherwise when you restart, your changes in `web.xml` will be overwritten.

For the second part of your question, updating a file in the `expanded` folder would never have any effect on the original archive.